# 1.0 Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I submitted my iOS app on appstoreconnect and woke up to this message.

> Please provide detailed answers to the following questions in your reply to this message in Resolution Center:
>
> - Does your app use background location? If yes, explain where the usage can be found in your binary?
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

Where exactly do I change the metadata values? Where and how exactly do I explain to them where I use user Location? Are they referring to the code itself?

Comment: Respond to the issue in resolution centre;  Explain the path through your app that uses background location.  Eg "Go to the "Alert me" screen, select a location to be alerted at" or whatever.  Metadata is the information you enter in App Store Connect that will be shown on the store.  It seems that your app includes the "location" background entitlement but they cannot find any background location functions.

Comment: if you are using background location service in your app then make them understand about its usage in the App. If they found it legitimate they will approve it else will tell you to disable the background location in the app. so defend your usage very well with them if you really need background location in you app.

Comment: This feels more like an iOS App store support question than a StackOverflow topic.